# How can I save an animation before it finishes rendering?

Tags: animation

I want to stop my render and save it before it's done rendering, I really don't need to render all the extra frames that I have but I don't want to restart my render or wait until it is done, (it's the same pose for about 40 frames.

Comment: Depends what your storage format is. If you're rendering to image files you can stop anytime with the previous frames already saved to disk. If you're rendering a video file, I don't think you can stop the render without creating an incomplete file that you may not be able to open. Pressing the ESC key will stop the render.

Comment: It's important to render to image files, that way you can stop it whenever you want, and you can't lose work.